# What is the Android equivalent to HTML's <label>?

Tags: android, html

all.  In HTML, I can check a checkbox or give focus to an input field by clicking on the associated `<label>` element.

```
<label for="pickles">Click to check the box</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="pickles">
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a similar Android convention, without setting a bunch of `onClick` listeners.  For the purposes of this question, assume that I would like a tap on the `TextView` to give focus to the following `EditText`:

```
<!-- Label -->
<TextView
    android:text="@string/email_label"
    style="@style/ProfileField.ProfileFieldLabel" />

<!-- Label's target -->
<EditText
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    style="@style/ProfileField.ProfileFieldInput" />
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you are missing is `android:hint="Email"` on your EditText which may give you all your looking for..

There is not a similar convention to this in Android, unfortunately what your asking is not a standard behavior when it comes to Android. There is something in the design support library which will handle this a little nicer though but it will still just look like and EditText. It is called `TextInputLayout` and can be added by including design library in gradle

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

example:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:hint="Label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```